# Changing font size and style

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have code for changing fonts but it's not working as it should :( I want to loop thrue all presentation and change font size and style by InputBox. Anyone can help me with this? Thanks so much!

```
Sub FormatTextBoxes()

Dim intSlide As Integer
Dim strNotes As String
Dim nts As TextRange
Dim strFont, intSize

intSize = InputBox("Please enter font size", "fontsize", "12")
strFont = InputBox("Please enter font", "font type", "Calibri")

    With ActivePresentation

        For intSlide = 1 To .Slides.Count
        Set nts = ActivePresentation.Slides(intSlide).NotesPage. _
        Shapes.Placeholders(2).TextFrame.TextRange
        With nts
            If intSize = "" Then intSize = 12
            .Paragraphs.Font.Size = intSize
            .Paragraphs.Font.Name = strFont

    End With

        Next intSlide
  End With
  MsgBox ("FormatNotes uitgevoerd")

End Sub
```

Comment: What objects do you want to change the font size/style for exactly? This code addresses the notes page text placeholder object only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will change the font size for all slide objects on all slides:

```
Option Explicit

' *************************************************************
' Purpose : PowerPoint macro to change font size for all shapes
'           on all slides across the active presentation
' Author  : Jamie Garroch of http://YOUpresent.co.uk/
' Inputs  : None
' Outputs : None
' *************************************************************
Sub ChangeFontSizeForSlideShapes()
  Dim oSld As Slide
  Dim oShp As Shape, oGrpItem As Shape
  For Each oSld In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each oShp In oSld.Shapes
      If oShp.Type = msoGroup Then
        For Each oGrpItem In oShp.GroupItems
          If oGrpItem.HasTextFrame Then
            oGrpItem.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 12
          End If
        Next ' oGrpItem
      Else
        If oShp.HasTextFrame Then
          oShp.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 12
        End If
      End If
    Next ' oShp
  Next ' oSld
End Sub
```